# How to parameterize ports in OpenShift JSON Project Template

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm trying to create a custom project template in `OpenShift Origin`. The `Service` configuration specifically, looks like below:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "${NAME}",
    "annotations": {
      "description": "Exposes and load balances the node.js application pods"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "web",
        "port": "${APPLICATION_PORT}",
        "targetPort": "${APPLICATION_PORT}",
        "protocol": "TCP"
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "name": "${NAME}"
    }
  }
},
```

where, `APPLICATION_PORT` is supplied as a user parameter:

```
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "APPLICATION_PORT",
    "displayName": "Application Port",
    "description": "The exposed port that will route to the node.js application",
    "value": "8000"
  },
```

When I try to use this template to create a project, I get the following error:

```
spec.ports[0].targetPort: Invalid value: "8000": must be an IANA_SVC_NAME (at most 15 characters, matching regex [a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])*...
```

I get a similar error in my `DeploymentConfig` as well, for the `http` ports in the `liveness` and `readiness` probes:

```
"readinessProbe": {
  "timeoutSeconds": 3,
  "initialDelaySeconds": 3,
  "httpGet": {
    "path": "/Info",
    "port": "${APPLICATION_ADMIN_PORT}"
  }
},
"livenessProbe": {
  "timeoutSeconds": 3,
  "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
  "httpGet": {
    "path": "/Info",
    "port": "${APPLICATION_ADMIN_PORT}"
  }
},
```

where, `APPLICATION_ADMIN_PORT`, again, is user-supplied.

Error:

```
spec.template.spec.containers[0].livenessProbe.httpGet.port: Invalid value: "8001": must be an IANA_SVC_NAME...

spec.template.spec.containers[0].readinessProbe.httpGet.port: Invalid value: "8001": must be an IANA_SVC_NAME...
```

I've been following https://blog.openshift.com/part-2-creating-a-template-a-technical-walkthrough/ to understand templates, and it, unfortunately, does not have any examples of *ports* being parameterized anywhere.

It almost seems as if *strings* are not allowed as the values of these ports. Is that the case? What's the right way to parameterize these values? <s>Should I switch to `YAML`?</s>

**Versions**:

`OpenShift Master: v1.1.6-3-g9c5694f`

`Kubernetes Master: v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5`

**Edit 1**: I tried the same configuration in `YAML` format, and got the same error. So, `JSON` vs `YAML` is *not* the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to parameterize non-string field values: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters

" Parameters can be referenced by placing values in the form "${PARAMETER_NAME}" in place of any **string field** in the template."

Templates are in the process of being upstreamed to Kubernetes and this limitation is being addressed there:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/templates.md

The proposal is being implemented in PRs 25622 and 25293 in the kubernetes repo.

edit:
Templates now support non-string parameters as documented here: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters

Comment: Thanks for responding, Ben! I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Is there an issue in OpenShift to track the use of that solution in Origin?  Would be good to link that here for future reference.

Comment: Yes, openshift templates now support non-string parameters:
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this option was available in 2016 when this post was added but now you can use ${{PARAMETER_NAME}} to parameterize non-string field values.

```
  spec:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    ports:
      - name: ${NAME}-port
        port: ${{PORT_PARAMETER}}
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: ${{PORT_PARAMETER}}
    sessionAffinity: None
```

Answer (score 0):

This may a be a bad practice but I'm using *sed* to substitute int parameters:

```
cat template.yaml | sed -e 's/PORT/8080/g' > proxy-template-subst.yaml
```

Template:

```
apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
kind: Template
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: ${NAME}
    namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
  spec:
    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
    ports:
      - name: ${NAME}-port
        port: PORT
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: PORT
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: NodePort
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
parameters:
- description: Desired service name
  name: NAME
  required: true
  value: need_real_value_here
- description: IP adress
  name: IP
  required: true
  value: need_real_value_here
- description: namespace where to deploy
  name: NAMESPACE
  required: true
  value: need_real_value_here
```